# Searching for a word that means... "even better than"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word that means... *"even better than"*

I want to use it in this sort of context...

> "It's a sitting duck."
>   "A sitting swan *-word here-*"

> "I'd like to buy some flour."
>   "Organic flour *-word here-*."

For some reason the word *nonetheless* pops into mind, but *nonetheless* means *however* so is obviously not it... the word I'm looking for is possibly similar sounding, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you looking for a word like better yet, or better still?

Comment: Why do you need than? "is better" is the phrase you need, right? Do you have "beats" in mind?

Comment: "Better yet" in that position sounds really weird, even borderline ungrammatical. It typically *begins* a sentence. (And of course it doesn't sound anywhere close to "nonetheless"...)

Comment: does anyone know if I could use nevertheless?

Comment: @Deb no, nevertheless does not have the meaning you're looking for

Comment: Something which would fit there is [FTW](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=FTW), "For the win", although it might be misunderstood as sarcastic.

Comment: _No less_ fits in fine and is normally used to show that the thing (or person) it is applied to is superior to all others. Here's a reference http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-less (from Cambridge Dictionaries, no less!)

Comment: @Frank - Yes! That's it, "No less" is what I was looking for, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: In some contexts (certainly OP's first example, if not the second), ***even*** works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The words 'preferably' or 'ideally' may work. For example:

"It's a sitting duck."
"A sitting swan, preferably." - does not work, but:

"I'd like to buy some flour."
"Organic flour, preferably." would seem acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with FumbleFingers, "...even" works, although it sounds a bit out-dated to my ears, possibly because it makes me think of old "Snagglepuss" cartoons: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CAf5i4TEA0

"I'm the strongest man in the room. The strongest man in town, even!"

You might be thinking of the word "moreover," which could go at the end of the sentence, but would be more likely to go at the beginning:

"I'm the strongest man in the room; moreover, I'm the strongest man in town!"

A couple other options:

"I'm the strongest man in the room, and the strongest man in town to boot!" (I'm the strongest man in town as well.)

"I'm the strongest man in the room; more to the point, I'm the strongest man in town!" (More importantly, I'm the strongest man in town.)

Answer (score 0):

Better than = superior

Even better than = even more superior

Answer (score 0):

"Certainly" works, and has an implied note of correction, and maybe a little disdainful reproach.

"Naturally" has the same correction, but a little nicer.

---

"It's a sitting duck."

"A sitting swan, certainly"

---

"I'd like to buy some flour."

"Organic flour, naturally."